# Selenium javascript util and elementIsEnabled

Tags: javascript, selenium

trying to click remove when input is enabled:
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls

```
const { expect } = require("chai"); 
const {Builder,By} = require("selenium-webdriver");
describe("Dynamic controls",function(){
it("Remove/add checkbox",async function(){
    const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
    await driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls");
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#input-example>button")).click();
    await driver.wait(driver.until.elementIsEnabled(By.CSS('#input-example > input[type=text]')), 30000);        
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#checkbox-example>button")).click();
});
```

});

I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementIsEnabled' of undefined

If I try:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(By.CSS('#input-example > input[type=text]')), 30000);
```

Have other error: ReferenceError: until is not defined

Comment: Did you import `until`?

Comment: If I do: const {Builder,By, until} = require("selenium-webdriver");
Have error: TypeError: element.isEnabled is not a function

Comment: It is `elementIsEnabled` (without dot).

Comment: my code: await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled 
error: TypeError: element.isEnabled is not a function

Comment: It should be without dot

Answer (score 0):

Right way

```
await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(driver.findElement(By.css('#input-example > input[type=text]'))), 10000);
```

`elementIsEnabled` accepts a `webelement`